# Trouble connecting to a TCP server through Docker on WSL 2

Tags: docker, rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL2 on Windows 10 using an Ubuntu image, and Docker for Desktop Windows (2.2.2.0) with the WSL integration.

I have a super basic rust tcp server. I *think* the only relevant bit is:

```
let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
println!("Listening on 8080");
for stream in listener.incoming() {
    println!("Received connection");
    let stream = stream.unwrap();
    handle_connection(stream);
}
```

I can `cargo install` and run the binary without issue; the line above prints, I can curl `localhost:8080` from WSL and see the response as I'd expect from the rest of the code.

I wanted to turn it into a docker image. Here's the Dockerfile.

```
FROM rust:1.40 as builder
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path . --root .

FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=builder ./bin/coolserver ./coolserver
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["./coolserver"]
```

I then do:

```
docker build -t coolserver .
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 coolserver
```

I see `Listening on 8080` as expected (i.e. no panic), but attempting to `curl localhost:8080` yields `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. This, I don't know what to make of. Logging suggests my program gets to the point where it reaches `listener.incoming()`, but does not enter into the block.

To see if it was something to do with my setup (Docker for Desktop, WSL, etc.) or my Dockerfile, I followed the README for the [docker-http-https-echo](https://github.com/mendhak/docker-http-https-echo) image, successfully. I can curl it on the specified ports.

I don't know how to debug further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8080").? Or something to listen beyond localhost? Localhost inside docker container is not the same as outside

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez that was it! misconceptions around the loopback ip I suppose. I still have issue #2 w.r.t. Ctrl-C not propagating, and I'm open to any input from you there, though I can ask that separately. if you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The Ctrl+C issue I think it is quite normal. It is your process which is consuming the Ctrl+C not the terminal. You can experience the same behavior with the telnet command.

Comment: I'm not so sure of that. I did some research, and I managed to run that http echo image just fine while still accepting the terminate. My little program handles it fine when running the executable directly. And I don't see anything in the echo app's Dockerfile that would suggest anything about handling signals correctly. The `-it` flags should be enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CarlosRafaelRamirez resolved it for me. It was as simple as binding to `0.0.0.0` rather than the loopback address `127.0.0.1`. More info here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/

Comment: It was not some one. It was  Carlos Rafael Ramirez. Normally you should ask him to post this as an answer rather than you accepting your response

Comment: @SajithSilva I did, check my first comment reply. I wanted to close this out. If they decide to answer, I'll remove this in favor of theirs.

Answer (score 1):

`EXPOSE` keyword is to open up ports for inter container communication for using these ports from host you have to use `-p 8080:8080`  while running docker via `docker run`

Comment: Oh, shoot, I _did_ try this but I forgot to address that. I'll update the post. In short, I instead receive `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`, and the Ctrl-C issue persists.

Comment: @esel don't you need any other file to run coolserver just one file, no need to copy any other dependencies

Comment: It's a multistage build, so the first stage I'm copying the source files so I can build it within Docker. In the second, I'm only copying the built binary into the final image. Am I misunderstanding you? More importantly, what does that have to do with the issue I'm facing?

Comment: If only part of files are copied then it's not docker issue but script issue , wanted to make sure you server has all files